# Implementing server-side regex validation from client-side regex

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox into which I only want alphanumeric characters and some punctuation; the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgDZk/) is here and the JavaScript implementation looks like this:

```
var TheCleanString = TheInput.replace(/(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+)/g, '');
```

As you can see, this only allows for alphanumeric characters, removes the leading whitespace and allows for parenthesis, dots and hyphens.

Now I want to use the SAME regex to validate that the string that's coming from the client passed this regex. I have something like this:

```
public bool MadeIt(TheCandidateString) 
{
   if (TheCandidateString passed this
       regex /(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\(\)\.\-]+)/g 
       then return true)
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're using asp.net look at the RegEx validator - that'll check it on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public bool MadeIt(string TheCandidateString) 
{
    string regex= @"yourRegex";
    var match = Regex.Match(TheCandidateString, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return match.Success;
}
```